# Set the sorting properties of gridview true but still columns are not becoming links

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have to do a sorting on headers of the gridview.

i have set the sorting property to true and also implemented the onsorting event.

But my headers are not coming up as links,what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your columns content is not sortable, for instance you have images. For that as a trick you can associate each image an index and bound the grid column to the index, rather than image.